# ios performing calculations with large numbers

Tags: ios

I am just multiplying two very big value in ios.

```
            value 1 999999999999
            value 2 99999
```

I am using the data type as double long i.e long long and this works for only too big values but not for small values like 10*23 something like that i get different answers example

```
           10.0*111.5 actual value in calculator is 1115 but i wat i get is 1110
```

please help me and i also want to roundof my answer to  3places like %.3f

Comment: You realize a `long` type will disregard 111.5 and use 111 right?

Comment: Are you sure you are using a long long? Looks like floating point to me. At least some of it does. Did you want to do 9999999999 * 9999 or 10*23 or 10.0 * 111.5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably what you are doing

```
long long left = 111.5; //Not good!  Will truncate to 111
long long right = 10.0; //10
long long result = left * right; //111 * 10 = 1110
```

This is what you should do

```
double left = 111.5;
double right = 10.0;
double result = left * right; //111.5 * 10.0 = 1115.0
```

If for some reason double is not enough you can go for `long double`.

Comment: i used the second one with long double and it is working. previously oly with double the values like 9999999999999 it is converting as e1